# Bash script to maximize all windows doesn't work

Tags: bash

I was trying to use this script to maximize all my windows but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be great.

```
#!/bin/bash
window_ids=$(wmctrl -l | cut -f1 -d " ")
for window_id in $window_ids
do
     wmctrl -i -r "$window_ids" -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `window_ids` within your loop but you seem to want `window_id`

I'm not very familiar with the wmctrl command but you should also generally avoid using word splitting to create a loop like that.

You could use an array:

```
mapfile -t window_ids < <(wmctrl -l | cut -f1 -d " ")
for window_id in "${window_ids[@]}"; do
```

mapfile/readarray will create an array `window_ids` with each line becoming it's own element

---

or maybe a while read loop:

```
wmctrl -l | while IFS=' ' read -r window_id _; do
```

In this case the output of `wmctrl -l` will be read with space as a delimiter.  The first field of each line will be assigned to `$window_id` and everything else will go into `$_`.

Comment: I tried both methods and somehow they both failed to work. The first did nothing while the second gave me the error `Cannot convert argument into number`.